# How to scrape data off a part of a site that requires user navigation

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

For example say I am trying to scrape from this page:

http://www.swtor.com/leaderboards/pvp/solo

It only shows top 50 results, pretty easy to go to this link and scrape those data. But say I want to scrape top 200. As a user I can click next page and see the next 50 result, but it doesn't generate a new url. The whole table is controlled by some JavaScript and not just explicit links that I can follow.

In situation like this how can you use code to navigate to the 2nd page and so forth to scrape the next set of records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the "Network" panel on you browser developer tools, you can see the XMLHttpRequest (XHR) requests the site does to load the table data:

```
http://www.swtor.com/lb/data?page=1&column=pvp_ranked_solo&season=6
http://www.swtor.com/lb/data?page=2&column=pvp_ranked_solo&season=6
```

This endpoint returns very handy JSONs and now it's just a matter of running as many requests as necessary.  Tip: the number of pages is also on the returned JSON, so there's no need to parse a single HTML page even if you want all records.