# How to programatically download a file from a website for which a static URL is not available or how to form a static URL

Tags: javascript, java, web-scraping, download

I want to download a file from a website using Java. The website URL is

```
https://340bopais.hrsa.gov
```

Once you hit the URL, you will see a menu 'Reports/Files'. Click that. Now the URL will become:

```
https://340bopais.hrsa.gov/reports
```

Then click 'Daily Reports'. Then click 'Covered Entity Daily Report'. A file will be downloaded to your machine.

I want to download this file using a Java program. I inspected the button 'Covered Entity Daily Report' and found the following HTML where a Javascript script is called. How can I click on this button using a Java program?

```
> <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkCEDailyReport" class="btn btn-primary
> btn-lg btn-block   " title=" Click here to download the Covered Entity
> Daily Report"
> href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkCEDailyReport','')">Covered Entity Daily Report</a>
```

Comment: can directly use [https://340bopais.hrsa.gov/reports](https://340bopais.hrsa.gov/reports) and then click 'Daily-Report'

Comment: Note: with developer tools, in your browser, you should be able to see the exact URL the file is downloaded from. That may help, unless it dynamically changes.

Comment: Thank you @David Conrad  . At least I am unable to find any URL when I press F12  while the request runs in IE. Maybe, I am missing something. If possible, can you please check from your side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scrape data off a part of a site that requires user navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328464/how-to-scrape-data-off-a-part-of-a-site-that-requires-user-navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for someone who has no code:

- Use this URL: https://340bopais.hrsa.gov/reports
- Connect to this URL with 'WebClient'
- Get the Page with 'HtmlPage'
- Wait until JavaScript files loaded.
- Download execute it and download result to given path.

---

Mabe [this already asked example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094637/downloading-files-behind-javascript-button-with-htmlunit) code can help you.

Comment: Thanks @LenglBoy . However, I am not sure after 3rd step. If possible, can you please form some initial code snippets for my example ?

Comment: @SatejKoli sry don´t saw comment: have a look [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers) and use a crawler you want. They are openSource so you can get snippets there. or search for the one with best examples. I´ve got no time now, but good luck to you.